# how to not apply jwt to every app in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, rest

I am working to make a simple ecommerce app. It work with Django as a backend and React for frontend. The trouble I am facing is when I tried to enter some product information (like title, price, image, description) through admin panel , It does not show in home page. When I tried to access its json form using Rest-framework api, it shows this

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3euOJ.png)

I have successfully added user model just following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLV19k3jZD89NsHDUqhqw9nZETyH1Qi-n8) but I think this is the cause. I think I have two authentication backends and jwt is not allowing me as admin user to add products. I searched it on google but could not figure what to do?

This is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for UsamaComputers project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from datetime import timedelta
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-p=i3^g82t202a!nauup+(ysg--_mkpl35_#qgs_6pyj6gkx#)a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    'accounts',
    'djoser',

    "corsheaders",
    'rest_framework',

    'frontend',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',

    'social',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'social_django'
   

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
     'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'UsamaComputers.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend')
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                 'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'UsamaComputers.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
       
    }
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '94.mbbs.2@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    # 'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   
)


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),

     'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',
    )
}
DJOSER = {
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'accounts/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    #  'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'accounts/email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'accounts/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY': 'djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy',
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS': ['http://127.0.0.1:8000'],
    'SETIALIZER': {
        'user_create':'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user':'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',

          'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
      
        'user_delete':'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer'

    }
}


SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '553150473290-o3398krcmdhr45jfiapcvlpplj9cldb5.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'Pba2WryBQ1KiplR7ZSV0aSH4'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'openid']
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = ['first_name', 'last_name']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
"""UsamaComputers URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include, re_path
from frontend.views import *
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
  
urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('wel/', ReactView.as_view(), name="something"),

    # path('', include('frontend.urls')),

    path('auth/',include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/',include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    
    path('auth/', include('djoser.social.urls')),
  

]

urlpatterns += [ re_path(r'^.*',TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'index.html'))]
```

and here is my usermodel:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user
    def create_superuser(self, email, password , **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
             **extra_fields,
           
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="" )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I really don't know what is the problem so I can't google this correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to this data can be seen by users that are not logged in ?
In this case, you need to specify the authentication_class in your view.

Comment: yes I want anybody to see this .

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: yes it worked.Thank you very much @AmirEsmaeili  Jazakallah